# Click event not firing because of a "pressed button" effect with :active pseudo-class

Tags: jquery, css, button

I'm trying to animate a div when it gets clicked, using a css ":active" pseudo-class. The div gets shifted by 10 pixels to the right and 10 pixels down:

```
#myButton:active {
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

See complete example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WdABS/

The problem is that if you click on the top or left border of the div (in red in the jsFiddle example), the mouse pointer is not over the div anymore when the button is released. So, neither *mouseup* nor *click* are fired.

Technically speaking, this behavior makes perfect sense. However, this is not what the final user would expect and I don't know how to fix it in a clean and easy way. I tried to put a parent container around the moving div and catch the click event from it, but it appeared to just make things more complex and didn't work very well either.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pure CSS: Use a Psuedo-Element

This is working for IE8+, Firefox, and Chrome (all those were tested). See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdABS/4/).

```
#myButton:active {
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
#myButton:active:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px; /* border plus shift amount */
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -20px; /* border plus shift amount */
}
```

Your `#myButton` will need either `position: relative` or `absolute` so the `:before` element locates itself correctly.

### Pure CSS: Shift with the Border Itself (CSS3)

*If the button did not already have a border on it*, then using the `border` property itself (with a transparent color) and `background-clip` (to not have the button color overlap the border), you can get the same functionality. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdABS/9/).

```
#myButton:active {
    border-top:10px transparent solid;
    border-left:10px transparent solid;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go ahead with your first solution. I can confirm it's working with recent versions of Opera and Safari as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for <input type="submit"> buttons :(

Comment: @JordanRieger: Of course not, [pseudo-elements don't work on inputs at all](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info).

Comment: @JordanRieger: If possible, the second solution using the border trick is working for me on an `input` in Firefox (that's all I tested) in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdABS/13/).

Comment: @ScottS yeah the problem with the border trick is that it screws up rounded corner styles -- which is the main reason we are using a styled button vs. a native button. See http://jsfiddle.net/3WTRT/.

Comment: @JordanRieger: Bummer. So far the only thing I have found to work at all is by adding a wrapper, but even that _does not work in IE_ (because it does not propagate the `active` state to the wrapper), so it is really not a solution. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WTRT/9/). If I think of anything else, I let you know.

Comment: @ScottS thanks, I appreciate the effort. Your solution works for many scenarios, unfortunately I have an existing ASP.Net site and it is a lot of work to override the default rendering of buttons as <input type="submit">.

Comment: There is still an area you can click, right on the text, that never triggers a click event.

Comment: @LincolnB: What browser? I cannot reproduce a non-click event.

Comment: Directly on top of the text, Chrome latest.  I solved the issue by making the element show on :before without :active - since its absolutely positioned its invisible doesn't affect the layout.

Answer (score 3):

So my idea is to bind the `mouseup` event handler to the document when the `mousedown` event handler is fired. Then you can run the code you wanted to run for `mouseup` and `click`. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdABS/12/) showing this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myButton').mousedown(function() { 
        debug('button down'); 
        $(document).on('mouseup', function(){
            $(document).off('mouseup');
            debug('button up');
            debug('click'); 
        });
    });
});

function debug(msg) {
    $('#debug').append('[' + msg + ']');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I prefer going with a 100% CSS solution, but this a nice one as well.